# Error Git SVN clone: Use of uninitialized value $sha1

Tags: git, perl, svn, git-svn

when I try to clone a SVN repo using the command

```
$ git svn clone https://subversion.random.repository
```

I am receiving the following error message:

```
Use of uninitialized value $sha1 in regexp compilation at /Library/Perl/5.30/Git/SVN.pm line 1023.
Tree is not a valid sha1: d3644f530de0da96374737160492a677f42c86b8
```

Although I am trying to download a particular repository, I tried to clone several other SVN repos, all causing the abovementioned error message.

I am working on a MacBook with macOS Big Sur (11.4) installed on it. Both Git and Subversion are installed via Homebrew, and Perl as well.

However, the script `/usr/local/opt/git/libexec/git-core/git-svn`, which the command `$ git svn clone ...` calls, is executed with the standard Perl version (5.30.2) installed on macOS, i.e., the first line of this script reads `#!/usr/bin/perl`.

[I know that this is in stark contrast to [previous discussions](https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-core/issues/52490), suggesting to replace `#!/usr/bin/perl` by `#!/usr/local/bin/perl` and therefore using the Perl installation (version 5.34) of Homebrew. However, for me, this causes yet another error message, namely `error: git-svn died of signal 11`].

Like described above, everything worked out perfectly until today. The only thing I did between last Friday and today is updating and upgrading Homebrew, and now, `$ git svn` is not working anymore.
I could not update the repository this morning. On top of that I unfortunately broke my local copy quite heavily, such that I now have to clone the whole repository again.

I would be very happy if somebody might have a clue where things are going wrong here, or what I might try in order to fix the problem.

Thanks a lot in advance.

Cheers,

Svennard

Comment: Might be test to take this up with the developers of `git` (or `git-svn` if it's a separate product; can't remember).

Answer (score 1):

the problem is solved!

I replaced the whole directory `/Library/Perl/5.30/Git`, which was created during the installation via Homebrew, by its pendant directly downloaded from the original source on [GitHub](https://github.com/git/git/tree/master/perl).

Now, everything works perfectly fine again. I will inform Homebrew that there might currently be a problem.